# Existence of Movie Clip Boolean without Error 1120

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
if(stage.contains(mc)){
    trace("mc exists");
}
```

How can I do something along this line without getting an error if "mc" does not exist? I've also tried:

```
if(mc){
    trace("mc exists");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check `mc` for `null` before `contains` check:

```
if(mc != null && stage.contains(mc)){
    trace("mc exists");
}
```

Or if you want to check if display object is part of display list, you could use simple function:

```
function myCheckForStage(object: DisplayObject):Boolean{
    return (object != null && object.stage != null)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code throws a compiler error at me when I remove the "mc" instance.

Comment: You don't want to use reference on display object? You could use `stage.getChildByName("mcName")`, it will return `null` if display object with name `mcName` will not be found in the list. And don't forget to give name to the display object you are looking for.

Comment: The problem was that I had accidentally formed "mc" as a button. After realizing my mistake I changed it back, but that didn't change all the created instances back to movie clips.